# Is this the optimal way to perform operations to MongoDB through a node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, web-services, database

I've writen this code where I start a **connection** to my MongoDB server and ***inside*** such connection I perform the web services code.

Is this an optimal or safe way? What would be better ways to implement this?

```
var express = require("express");
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var servidor = new express();

var BSON = mongodb.BSONPure;
servidor.use(express.static(__dirname+"/publico"));
servidor.use(express.bodyParser());
var cliente_mongodb = mongodb.MongoClient;

cliente_mongodb.connect("mongodb://localhost/db_escuela", function(err, db_escuela){
    if(err){
        console.log("Error de conexion"+err);
    }else{
        console.log("Se ha conectado a la base de datos");
        var cl_alumnos = db_escuela.collection("cl_alumnos");

        servidor.get("/alumnos",function(peticion, respuesta){
            cl_alumnos.find().toArray(function(err,respuesta_db){
                respuesta.send(respuesta_db);
            });
        });

        servidor.get("/alumnos/:id",function(peticion,respuesta){
            var id = new BSON.ObjectID(peticion.params.id);
            cl_alumnos.findOne({'_id':id},function(err,respuesta_db){
                respuesta.send(respuesta_db);           
            });
        });

        servidor.post("/alumnos",function(peticion,respuesta){
            var nuevo_alumno={
                nombre:peticion.body.nombre,
                edad:peticion.body.edad,
                promedio:peticion.body.promedio
            };
            cl_alumnos.insert(nuevo_alumno,function(err,respuesta_db){
                console.log("Se ha insertado: "+JSON.stringify(respuesta_db));
                respuesta.send(respuesta_db);           
            });
        });

        servidor.delete("/alumnos/:id",function(peticion,respuesta){
            var alumno_eliminar = {
                _id : new BSON.ObjectID(peticion.params.id)
            }

            cl_alumnos.remove(alumno_eliminar,function(err,respuesta_db){
                if(err)
                    console.log("No se ha podido eliminar el registro");
                else
                    respuesta.send("Registro Eliminado");               
            });         
        });

        servidor.put("/alumnos/:id",function(peticion,respuesta){
            var id_editado={
                _id : new BSON.ObjectID(peticion.params.id)         
            };
            var alumno_editado={
                nombre:peticion.body.nombre,
                edad:peticion.body.edad,
                promedio:peticion.body.promedio
            };      
            cl_alumnos.update(id_editado, alumno_editado, function(err, respuesta_db){
                if(err)
                {
                    console.log("Error:"+err);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("Resultado "+respuesta_db);
                    respuesta.send("Actualizacion Exitosa");
                }
            });
        });


        servidor.listen(8080,function(){
            console.log("El servidor esta escuchando en el puerto 8080");
        });             
    }


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fine, and safe.  The connection to MongoDB is only made once.  You are adding anonymous functions with a reference to this connection to the middleware for your server.

As far as code organization goes, some may suggest breaking this up a bit.  For an application of the size above, I see no problem.  If you plan to grow, some refactoring may be warranted.

Comment: Running the server in the success callback of the connection means that every request has the same connection object, right? Is this ok from a best practice point of view? I'm asking this not to criticize your answer, but to understand your point.

Comment: @AlbertoZaccagni, That is correct.  Each request will share the same connection to MongoDB.  This is actually encouraged.  You don't want the overhead of connecting to MongoDB every time a request is made... by sharing a connection, you can reuse it for subsequent requests.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't be afraid to use ODM like Mongoose. It more easier than you think and will solve any problems you have.